# Livewire/Alpine Dynamic # of Toggle Binding

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a form that displays a number of [toggle switches](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/toggles).

[image]

The amount of switches is dynamic based on the "permissions" in a table. how do I bind these so that when they are clicked, the data is posted back to livewire? The 'Non-dynamic' answer I have found is x-data="{isChecked: @entangle('foo')}" but this obviously doesn't work if I have an unknown number of items and not a single 'foo'.

I have tried a method wire:click="update({{ $value->id }})" but this only passes back to livewire the id of the element that has been clicked, not it's state (on or off).

```
@foreach($permissions as $key => $value)
   <div>
      <span>
         <span>{{ $value->name }}</span>
         <span>{{ $value->description }}</span>
      </span>
      <button type="button"
         x-data="{isChecked: {{ $value->allowed ? 1 : 0 }}}"
         @click="isChecked = !isChecked"
         {# wire:click? doesn't send state #}
         wire:click="update"
         :class="{'bg-liteblue': isChecked, 'bg-gray-200': !isChecked }"
         class="relative..."
         role="switch"
         :aria-checked="isChecked"
         aria-labelledby="availability-label">
         <span class="sr-only">Use setting</span>
         <span aria-hidden="true"
            :class="{'translate-x-5': isChecked, 'translate-x-0': !isChecked }"
            class="translate-x-5 transition ease-in-out duration-200"></span>
      </button>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

I would like each toggle to update the database as its clicked (not in one final submit). How do I pass the state back to the livewire controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with a child component called 'permission-toggle', that way each toggle could be responsible for holding it's state rather than an array, and then instantiated it inside the parent component with

```
@foreach($permissions as $permission)

        <livewire:permission-toggle :group="$selectedGroup" :permission="$permission" :key="$selectedGroup.'.'.$permission->slug">

@endforeach
```

The parent "permission-form" component is responsible for getting all the permissions from the database, (so there's only one big call on load) and then each individual "permission-toggle" component is responsible for updating itself. (individual database calls) The livewire controller for permission toggle is as below

```
class PermissionToggle extends Component
{
    public bool   $checked;
    public string $name;
    public string $description;
    public string $slug;
    public string $group;

    public function mount($permission)
    {
        $this->checked     = $permission->allowed;
        $this->name        = $permission->name;
        $this->description = $permission->description;
        $this->slug        = $permission->slug;
    }

    public function updating($a, bool $checked)
    {
        $group = Group::where('slug', $this->group)->first();

        if($checked === true)
            $group->assignPermissions($this->slug);
        else
            $group->revokePermissions($this->slug);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.permission-toggle');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the '@entangle' in the x-data line. The following is the example on https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js  about 1/2 way down.  This entangles the javascript variable = open to the livewire public property $showDropdown.  When you change the value of open, the public property $showDropdown will be changed to the equivalent of open.  However, I think the communication is only one way - apine to livewire.

```
<div x-data="{ open: @entangle('showDropdown') }">
```

or you could use something like this

```
<button x-on:click="$wire.someMethod($value->id)">xxxxxxx</button>
```

The param would identify which toggle you clicked on.  The livewire method - someMethod() - would then save the choice in the DB.

I am having a similar problem.  the following is what I am trying.  When the click event is fired off, it toggles the alpine variable 'enableit'.  the alert(enableit) shows the state being toggled.  However the alert('{{ $isEnabled }}') shows up blank.  However, If I go look at the json delivered back in the Console, I see the $isEnabled property being toggled, but opposit of the enableit variable.

```
@props([
    'choice' => 'Make Administrator?',
    'desc' => 'We encourage you to make your spouse / partner an administrator',
    'isEnabled' => false,
])
<div
    x-data="{ open: @entangle('showToggleButton').defer,
              enableit: @entangle('isEnabled')}"
    class="flex items-center justify-between"
>
  <span x-show="open" class="flex-grow flex flex-col" id="availability-label">
    <span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 mr-4">{{ $choice }}</span>
    <span class="text-sm text-gray-500 mr-4">{{ $desc }}</span>
  </span>
    <!-- Enabled: "bg-indigo-600", Not Enabled: "bg-gray-200" -->
    <button x-show="open" type="button"
            @click="enableit = !enableit; alert(enableit); alert('{{ $isEnabled }}')"
            class="{{ ($isEnabled) ? 'bg-indigo-600' : 'bg-gray-200' }}  relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            role="switch" aria-checked="enableit" aria-labelledby="availability-label">
        <span x-show="open"  class="sr-only">Use setting</span>
        <!-- Enabled: "translate-x-5", Not Enabled: "translate-x-0" -->
        <span x-show="open" aria-hidden="!enableit"
              class="{{ ($isEnabled) ? 'translate-x-5' : 'translate-x-0' }} pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

btw, you mentioned

```
# wire:click? doesn't send state #
```

I believe you should use $wire.click in the alpine component.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few levels at which one could answer this question.  The first is:

**Why `@entangle?`**

If you're going to synch the data through Livewire, then strictly speaking (at least form what I understand from your code), you don't need to entangle the data with Alpine.

The second level is:

**If you insist on using `@entangle`**

You don't need to create a completely new component.  You can entangle an array (and an array of arrays, and an array of array of arrays):

Your accepted solution works, no doubt.  But in my opinion it looks like quite a verbose solution.  I don't like burying layers of classes/files to solve a solution that should be "though of" as a single concept.  It makes the long-term maintenance a bit more time-consuming when you have to flip through multiple files.  (Personal preference perhaps, whatever.)

The way I'd approach this is as follows.  Define a single array in your original Livewire component:

```php
class PropertiesPage extends Component
{
    // in the real world, this array would be populated from a DB
    public array $permissions = [
        'inventory' =>  [ // group level
            'view_inv' => [ // permission level
                'description' => 'View Inventory',
                'slug'        => '/viewinv',
                'is_checked'  => true,
            ],
            'update_inv' => [
                'description' => 'Modify Inventory',
                'slug'        => '/modinv',
                'is_checked'  => false,
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

In your `blade.php` file, you then entangle the entire array:

```html
    <div x-data="dbPermissions: @entangle('permissions')">
        <p>Blah...</p>
    </div>
```

You can then use Blade's `@foreach` to loop through the array in a similar manner to the way you did in the question.  **However**, as highlighted in my first point above, why bother `@entangle`-ing if your logic and synching happens in Blade/Livewire?  Surely the whole point if wanting to `@entangle` in the first place is to use Alpine's solution for looping, which is to say you could do something like this:

```html
    <template x-for="(perms, group) in dbPermissions">
        <p x-text="group"></p>
        <template x-for="(props, permId) in perms">
            <input type="radio" x-model="dbPermissions[group][permId].is_checked">
        </template>
    </template>
```

*All my code is pseudo-code of course, since I don't have a full handle on your actual solution.  My intention on this site is always to share the concepts openly, rather than solve your particular problem down to a T.*

Comment: Just noticed how similar this answer is to another one I gave recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337244/nested-components-in-livewire-with-alpinejs-and-entangle-directive/69487532#69487532 .  Indeed how similar the underlying questions were.  My other answer contains actual code that I tested, and is not based on pseudo-code.